# Creating a Data Dictionary with example data (SQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am looking to run a script on a SQL database to create a Data Dictionary with an example of the data for each field.

To keep it simple I would just like to include the data from the first row of each table along with each table name and column name

So something like this:

| Table Name | Field Name | Example Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer | ID | CU1 |
| Customer | Title | Mrs |
| Customer | Name | Anne |
| Customer | Order No | ORD1 |

etc.

Is there an easy way to do this with a SQL script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somebody smarter than me could probably optimize this and remove the cursor but the Dynamic SQL was giving me a headache.  I think in this scenario, a cursor is acceptable

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##DataDictionary
CREATE TABLE ##DataDictionary (TableName SYSNAME, ColumnName SYSNAME, SampleData NVARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME
DECLARE @ColumnName SYSNAME
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
  SELECT t.name AS TableName,c.Name AS ColumnName 
  FROM sys.tables t
    JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id

OPEN cur

FETCH cur  INTO @TableName,@ColumnName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = ''
    SELECT @SQL = '
    INSERT INTO ##DataDictionary(TableName,ColumnName,SampleData)
    SELECT '''+@TableName+''','''+@ColumnName+'''
    ,(SELECT TOP 1 '+QUOTENAME(@ColumnName)+' FROM '+QUOTENAME(@TableName)+' ORDER BY NEWID()) -- NewID randomly selects a sample row
    '
    print @SQL
    EXEC (@SQL)

    FETCH cur  INTO @TableName,@ColumnName
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur

SELECT * from ##DataDictionary
```